# Create Google Cloud VM using a dockerfile

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I know how to launch a Compute Engine VM. I know how to install docker, create an image from a dockerfile, and launch a container.

What I want to do is to use a dockerfile as the specification to spin up a VM. For example, go to https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances and use the dockerfile below to create my VM:

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM rocker/rstudio:latest

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
#SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]

# collect build args
ARG USER
ARG UID
ARG GID

# install stuff
RUN apt update && apt install -y \
        vim \
        iputils-ping \
        wget

# create user $USER
RUN groupadd -g $GID $USER
RUN useradd -rm -d /home/$USER -s /bin/bash -u $UID -g $GID $USER
RUN usermod -a -G sudo $USER
RUN chpasswd <<<$USER:weakpass
```

There are a zillion guides for the former. But I can't find any for the latter.

Comment: Dockerfiles are used to build containers. Products such as Terraform and Packer are used to create virtual machines.

Comment: or if you are looking for a google specific way of creating resources from a template file, look into [deployment manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/manage-cloud-resources-deployment). Technically, you can create Compute Engine VMs (or other GCP resources) with Dockerfile (for example using [Google Cloud SDK image](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/)) but is this what you want?..